# @RequestScoped + new thread

Tags: java, ejb, java-ee-6, java-ee-7, open-liberty

We use javaEE RequestScoped with OpenLiberty and new threads via EJB @Asynchronous. I am just curious what the actual value comes from when we inject RequestScoped bean inside a new thread? Will the RequestScoped bean be freshly initialized? Or will it be pulled from the latest request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenLiberty, you'll get a new request scope every time you make an EJB `@Asynchronous` call, meaning that you'll get a new freshly initialized instance of any injected `RequestScoped` beans while you're within that method call.